# How can I have PyTorch code run via a Docker script use my Apple Silicon GPU (via PyTorch MPS)?

Tags: docker, pytorch, gpu

I have a Docker script `run.sh` that runs some PyTorch code in a Docker container.

The PyTorch code uses `device = torch.device('mps' if torch.backends.mps.is_available() else 'cpu')` to run everything on my MacBook Pro's GPU via the **[PyTorch MPS (Metal Performance Shader) backend](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/mps.html)**.

If I run the Python script `ml.py` without Docker, i.e. in my own Python environment, everything runs on the GPU as expected.

But if I run the same code via the Docker script, it only runs on the CPU, which means `torch.backends.mps.is_available()` must have returned `False`.

How can I ensure that the Docker container also uses my GPU?

I've seen that for NVIDIA GPUs there is a command `docker run --gpus all nvidia-test` that enables GPU support but I haven't seen anything like that for Apple Silicon GPUs.

Comment: Docker is Linux, there is no Linux support for the MPS device, since it is MacOS specific.

Comment: I see. So Apple would have to release something equivalent to `nvidia-docker` for this to become feasible?

Comment: No, they would have to implement docker natively, people often forget that Docker is technology based on Linux features, when you use Docker on Windows, you use Linux in a virtual machine, similarly for MacOS.

Comment: You likely need a specific set of drivers for the docker container to access the MPS device. This may be useful https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/81224